# I need to refresh the form but still keep the value of checkbox intact

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jsp-tags

I have a checkbox inside a struts form along with other fields and on checking or unchecking of which  the form needs to be submitted but the value of checkbox, checked or unchecked needs to be intact. (Form validations are done using struts action class).
How to achieve this in my jsp?

Comment: Please provide the code your currently have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using HTML5 then you can use localStorage API.

e.g.

```
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
    // Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Or you can store the data in 
    `cookies` temporary then delete it.

Or you can send the checkbox data to  `server side API` 
  before page refreshing and then retrieve it on page load from same API or

You can check for storage plugins.

Choice is yours

UPDATE :

Suppose your checkbox  I'd is `mycheck`

then using JavaScript you can do like this.

```
var checkvalue =document.getElementById("mycheck").checked;

localStorage.setItem("lastname", checkvalue);
```

Using jQuery:

```
var checkvalue =$("#mycheck").val();

localStorage.setItem("lastname", checkvalue);
```

Comment: What you said is OK , but if I need to put the value of checkbox, ie checked or unchecked in place of your "Smith" in this code  localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith"); , how will I achieve it.

Comment: Thanks Riyaj for the update. Will test and let you know if my requirement works.